# Laravel Exception Property [location] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm creating a search option for a job database and I added some scopes to my job Model namely "salary", "tags", "keyword", and "locations" to narrow down results that the users wants to see. all the scopes work fine even when chained Except "locations", I can't make this work. I think I'm doing something wrong with the query.

heres my job model relation with the Location model and the scope I use.

```
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Location::class, 'locationable');
    }



    public function scopeLocations($query, $type)
    {
        return $query->location->where('country', 'LIKE', '%' . $type->location . '%')
                                // ->orWhere(['location', 'LIKE', '%' . $type->location . '%'],["specific_location" , 'LIKE', '%' . $type->location . '%'])
                                ->get();
    }

    public function scopeKeyword($query, $type)
    {
        return $query->where('ad_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $type->keyword . '%');
    }

    public function scopeTag($query, $type)
    {
        return $query->withAnyTags($type->include_tags)->get();
    }

    public function scopeSalary($query, $type)
    {
        return $query->whereBetween('salary',[$type->min, $type->max]);
    }
```

heres my location model

```
class Location extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function locationable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Heres the controller which accesses the scope

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{

    public function jobsearch(SearchValidation $request){
        $jobs = Job::keyword($request)->salary($request)->locations($request);
        return $jobs;
    }
}
```

and lastly heres the error I get

```
   {message: "Property [location] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.",…}
exception: "Exception"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php"
line: 1316
message: "Property [location] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance."
trace: [{file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\app\model\Job.php", line: 56, function: "__get",…}, {,…}, {,…},…]
0: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\app\model\Job.php", line: 56, function: "__get",…}
1: {,…}
2: {,…}
3: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\app\Http\Controllers\SearchController.php", line: 18,…}
4: {function: "jobsearch", class: "App\Http\Controllers\SearchController", type: "->"}
5: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php",…}
6: {,…}
7: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php",…}
8: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php",…}
9: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",…}
10: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",…}
11: {,…}
12: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",…}
13: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",…}
14: {,…}
15: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",…}
16: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",…}
17: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",…}
18: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",…}
19: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",…}
20: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",…}
21: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",…}
22: {,…}
23: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",…}
24: {,…}
25: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",…}
26: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",…}
27: {,…}
28: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",…}
29: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",…}
30: {,…}
31: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",…}
32: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",…}
33: {,…}
34: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",…}
35: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",…}
36: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php", line: 57,…}
37: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",…}
38: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",…}
39: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php",…}
40: {,…}
41: {,…}
42: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\public\index.php", line: 55, function: "handle",…}
43: {file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\testingphase\server.php", line: 21, function: "require_once"}
```

can someone point out where I'm having trouble? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the relation on an Eloquent Builder causing the error. Relation are available on models instances in `$query->location->where`.

To add conditions on relation see the ["Querying Relationship Existence" section](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) on documentation.

To keep using scopes you should move `scopeLocations` to `Location` model replacing `$query->location->where` with `$query->where`, then on controller:

```php
<?php
Job::keyword($request)
    ->salary($request)
    // name of relation function and callback
    ->whereHas('location', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->locations($request);
    })
```

Also I recommend that you avoid using `get()` in scope functions, and pass the value instead of `$request`: `Job::keyword($request->keyword)`

Comment: I've done as you said and now I'm receiving a different error. I guess this has something to do with relations. I'll try to figure this one out. but here's the error in case you already know the answer
`exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jobs.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `locations` where `jobs`.`id` = `locations`.`locationable_id` and `locations`.`locationable_type` = App\Model\Job and `country` LIKE %Florida%)" `

Comment: @newtsullivan does `get()` call still on `scopeLocations` functon? if yes move it to controller

Comment: Thanks! It gives no error anymore however. the data it gives me back disregards the location part. all the scopes work except for the location. the data given is at random location. not what I specified in the query.

Comment: Hi! Ive got it to work finally, I removed the scopeLocations from the Locations model and moved it to the search controller. the reason being is when I tried to dd() ->sql() the statement does not include the query in the scopeLocations. here's the final controller

Comment: heres my search controller 

`public function jobsearch(SearchValidation $request){
        
        $jobs = Job::keyword($request->keyword)->salary($request)->whereHas('location', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereHasMorph('locationable', 'App\Model\Job', function (Builder $query) use ($request) { 
                $query->where('country', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->location . '%');
            });
        })->get();

        return JobResourceApplicant::collection($jobs);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in in the `$request` you passed in `locations()` method or scope this object parameter doesn't have the `type` property

In your SearchController make sure that the `request` object has `type` property

```
->locations($request)
```

because you called it in the `Job model` in `$type->location`

```
public function scopeLocations($query, $type)
    {
        return $query->location->where('country', 'LIKE', '%' . $type->location . '%')
                                // ->orWhere(['location', 'LIKE', '%' . $type->location . '%'],["specific_location" , 'LIKE', '%' . $type->location . '%'])
                                ->get();
}
```